# Estimating Markov chain transition probabilities from data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, markov-process, transition-matrix

In a discrete time and space Markov chain, I know the formula to estimate the transition probabilities $$p_{ij} = \frac{n_{ij}}{\sum_{j \in S} n_{ij}}$$ I'm not sure however how you can find this is derived from the likelihood function $$L(p) = \prod_{i\in S}\prod_{j \in S} {p_{ij}}^{n_{ij}}$$

Comment: Can you try taking partial derivative of $\log L(p)$ with respect to $p_{ij}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $K$ be the number of states. The log-likelihood is
$$
\ell(p) = \sum_{i =1}^K \sum_{j =1}^K n_{ij} \log p_{ij}
$$

We now want to take the partial derivatives with respect to each $p_{ij}$, but remember that for each $i$ we have the constraint
$\sum_{j =1}^K p_{ij}=1$, so we can set the last transition probability equal to $p_{iK} = 1 - \sum_{j =1}^{K-1} p_{ij}$.

Differentiating with respect to $p_{ij}$  and setting to zero gives
$$
\frac{n_{ij}}{\hat{p}_{ij}} - \frac{n_{iK}}{\hat{p}_{iK}}=0 \quad \text{for} \quad j=1,\ldots,K-1
$$
and we deduce that
$$
\frac{n_{i1}}{\hat{p}_{i1}} = \frac{n_{i2}}{\hat{p}_{i2}}= \ldots = \frac{n_{iK}}{\hat{p}_{iK}}
$$
In other words, we have $\hat{p}_{ij} \propto n_{ij}$ and it follows that the MLE is
$$
\hat{p}_{ij}= \frac{n_{ij}}{\sum_{j =1}^K n_{ij}}
$$